# Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=EXC_I386_GPFLT)

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

In my swift project, I have two classes that work together to hold Pixel values of an image to be able to modify red, green, blue and alpha values. An `UnsafeMutableBufferPointer` holds lots of bites that are comprised of the Pixel class objects.

I can interact with that the class that holds the `UnsafeMutableBufferPointer<Pixel>` property. I can access all of the properties on that object and that all works fine. The only problem I'm having with the `UnsafeMutableBufferPoint<Pixel>` is trying to loop through it with my Pixel object and it keeps crashing with the Thread 1: `EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=EXC_I386_GPFLT)` exception.

```
init!(image: UIImage)
{
    _width = Int(image.size.width)
    _height = Int(image.size.height)

    guard let cgImage = image.cgImage else { return nil }

    _width = Int(image.size.width)
    _height = Int(image.size.height)
    let bitsPerComponent = 8

    let bytesPerPixel = 4
    let bytesPerRow = _width * bytesPerPixel
    let imageData = UnsafeMutablePointer<Pixel>.allocate(capacity: _width * _height)
    let colorSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB()

    var bitmapInfo: UInt32 = CGBitmapInfo.byteOrder32Big.rawValue
    bitmapInfo |= CGImageAlphaInfo.premultipliedLast.rawValue & CGBitmapInfo.alphaInfoMask.rawValue
    guard let imageContext = CGContext(data: imageData, width: _width, height: _height, bitsPerComponent: bitsPerComponent, bytesPerRow: bytesPerRow, space: colorSpace, bitmapInfo: bitmapInfo) else { return nil }
    imageContext.draw(cgImage, in: CGRect(origin: CGPoint.zero, size: image.size))

    _pixels = UnsafeMutableBufferPointer<Pixel>(start: imageData, count: _width * _height)
}
```

This function is the part that is crashing the program. The exact part that is crashing is the for loop that is looping through the rgba.pixels. rgba.pixels is the UnsafeMutableBufferPointer.

```
func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : Any])
{
    let image: UIImage = info[UIImagePickerControllerEditedImage] as! UIImage!

    let rgba = RGBA(image: image)!

    for pixel in rgba.pixels
    {
        print(pixel.red)
    }

    self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil);
}
```

This is the constructor where I create the `UnsafeMutableBufferPointer<Pixel>`. Is there an easier way to do this and still be able to get the RBGA values and change them easily.

The Pixel class is a `UInt32` value this is split into four `UInt 8` values.

Am I using the wrong construct to hold those values and if so, is there a safer or easier construct to use? Or am I doing something wrong when accessing the Pixel values?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how I got the pixels of an image -

```
// Grab and set up variables for the original image
    let inputCGImage = inputImage.CGImage
    let inputWidth: Int = CGImageGetWidth(inputCGImage)
    let inputHeight: Int = CGImageGetHeight(inputCGImage)

    // Get the colorspace that will be used for image processing (RGB/HSV)
    let colorSpace: CGColorSpaceRef = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB()!

    // Hardcode memory variables
    let bytesPerPixel = 4 // 32 bits = 4 bytes
    let bitsPerComponent = 8 // 32 bits div. by 4 components (RGBA) = 8 bits per component
    let inputBytesPerRow = bytesPerPixel * inputWidth

    // Get a pointer pointing to an allocated array to hold all the pixel data of the image
    let inputPixels = UnsafeMutablePointer<UInt32>(calloc(inputHeight * inputWidth, sizeof(UInt32)))

    // Create a context to draw the original image in (aka put the pixel data into the above array)
    let context: CGContextRef = CGBitmapContextCreate(inputPixels, inputWidth, inputHeight, bitsPerComponent, inputBytesPerRow, colorSpace, CGImageAlphaInfo.PremultipliedLast.rawValue | CGBitmapInfo.ByteOrder32Big.rawValue)!

    CGContextDrawImage(context, CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: inputWidth, height: inputHeight), inputCGImage)
```

Keep in mind this is not Swift 3 syntax incase that's what you're using, but that's the basic algorithm. Now to grab the individual color values of each pixel, you will have to implement these functions -

```
func Mask8(x: UInt32) -> UInt32
{
    return x & 0xFF
}

func R(x: UInt32) -> UInt32
{
    return Mask8(x)
}

func G(x: UInt32) -> UInt32
{
    return Mask8(x >> 8)
}

func B(x: UInt32) -> UInt32
{
    return Mask8(x >> 16)
}

func A(x: UInt32) -> UInt32
{
    return Mask8(x >> 24)
}
```

To create a completely new color after processing the RGBA values, you use this function -

```
func RGBAMake(r: UInt32, g: UInt32, b: UInt32, a: UInt32) -> UInt32
{
    return (Mask8(r) | Mask8(g) << 8 | Mask8(b) << 16 | Mask8(a) << 24)
}
```

To iterate through the pixels array, you do it as so -

```
var currentPixel = inputPixels
for _ in 0..<height
    {
        for i in 0..<width
        {
            let color: UInt32 = currentPixel.memory
            if i < width - 1
            {
                print(NSString(format: "%3.0f", R(x: color), terminator: " "))
            }
            else
            {
                print(NSString(format: "%3.0f", R(x: color)))
            }
            currentPixel += 1
        }
    }
```